# Append data on Google Sheets script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script where a user inputs some information on the user tab.  Then, they hit a button which triggers a script to dump the information they input into a separate tab which I'm calling the repository.  This code is working flawlessly:

```
function dumpInputsToRepository(button) {
var userSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var userTab = userSheet.getSheetByName('PhoneSelect');
var firstRow = 6;
var range = userTab.getRange(firstRow, 1, userTab.getLastRow() - firstRow +1, 10);
var data = range.getValues();

var repTab = userSheet.getSheetByName('Rep');
repTab.getRange(repTab.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, 10).setValues(data);
```

In the repository list, I want to add two columns of data on the right side of what is being input.  Specifically, I want a column which produces the timestamp of when the button was pushed, and I want another column which produces the email address of the person who pushed the button.

For the timestamp, I had the idea to add an extra column in the user tab with =Now() function, and then just extend the inputs to 11 columns of data being moved to the repository.  That works, but I figure there is a more elegant solution which I could input.

Getting the email to be produced in the final column has eluded me.  I've tried to rework some code from here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()

But I can't get my email address to appear anywhere let alone appended to to the data that is being sent from the user sheet to repository sheet.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rather than write a formula with `=NOW()`, which will be constantly updated, write a variable that is a `Date` object: `const now = new Date();` Note that you must write rectangular data, so every element of the `data` array must be an array of the same length. You mention you can't get *your* email address to appear - is someone else's appearing? or just nothing?

Comment: The =Now() formula would work for my purposes since, when it is transferred to the repository, it is no longer a live formula, but instead the values of the date and time at the instant the code was triggered.  What do you mean by 'rectangular data'?

Comment: I can't get any email address to appear.

Comment: `[ [r1c1, r1c2], [r2c1] ]` is not rectangular, because there is only element in the 2nd element of the array, while the first element has 2 elements. Google has rules about `Session`, please review the documentation.

Comment: If you are the only one that will run the script add your email directly `var email = 'myname@example.com'`.

Comment: I won't be the only one who is a running the script, and we need to know who ran it.  On a separate sheet I have been able to get the email address to be printed in a specified cell with this code: `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(email)`    But I don't know how to have the email address appear in the repository tab to the right of  each row of data that is coming from the user tab.